# How to duplicate and replace certain values in duplicated records multiple times using R and dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, duplicates

I have records in a dataframe that I want to duplicate multiple times, and apply some changes to each iteration of duplicate rows.

Using the following dataframe:

```
name <- c("Kiwi","Orange","Apple")
val1 <- c(1,9,10)
val2 <- c(1,1,1)

df <- data.frame(name, val1, val2)
```

I can duplicate the row where name == "Apple" and replace the name in the duplicate row:

```
df.2 <- df %>% 
            filter(name == "Apple") %>% 
            mutate(name = "Strawberry") %>%
            bind_rows(., df)
```

However running this operation more than once does not work as expected:

```
df.2 <- df %>% 
            filter(name == "Apple") %>% 
            mutate(name = "Strawberry") %>%
            bind_rows(., df) %>%
            filter(name == "Apple") %>% 
            mutate(name = "Dragonfruit") %>%
            bind_rows(., df)
```

Expected result:

```
val1 <- c(10,10,1,9,10)
val2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
name <- c("Dragonfruit","Strawberry","Kiwi","Orange","Apple")

expected.result <- data.frame(name, val1, val2)
```

Comment: Step through it line by line - there's still only one row with `name == 'Apple'` on the second pass, and then you're binding it to the original unchanged `df`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Because when I run the operation the first time, the row with name == "Apple" is successfully duplicated to produce a row with name == "Strawberry".

Comment: @Mark has worked through the code line-by-line as I suggested in their answer below. It definitely works the first time - the issue is the selection on the second pass essentially resets everything.

Comment: @thelatemail ah yes I understand what you mean after looking at Mark's answer, thank you for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
df.2 <- bind_rows(df, 
                  df %>% filter(name == "Apple") %>% mutate(name = "Strawberry"),
                  df %>% filter(name == "Apple") %>% mutate(name = "Dragonfruit"))
```

Of course, it's more concise to make a new variable for `df %>% filter(name == "Apple")`, and then use that, but not *massively* more, so I didn't, but you can.

To find the issue with your code, let's go through it line by line:

```
df.2 <- df %>% 
            filter(name == "Apple") %>% 
            mutate(name = "Strawberry") %>%
```

at this point, the dataframe is one row `Strawberry   10    1`

```
            bind_rows(., df) %>%
```

this value is added to the beginning of the old dataframe

```
            filter(name == "Apple") %>%
```

...but then you promptly remove it again, by filtering only for rows where the name is "Apple"

```
            mutate(name = "Dragonfruit") %>%
            bind_rows(., df)
```

hence, at the end, you don't have the strawberry row anymore.

Comment: ah okay so the filter argument is not just "getting" a row, it's filtering them out of the dataframe (me facepalming myself). not sure why I just ignored the way the function works lol.

Comment: I mean, it's not *not* getting a row (in that, filtering rows and getting rows are two ways of saying the same thing). It depends what your rules are. You can look at `filter(name == "Apple")` as it *removing* all rows where the name *isn't* "Apple", or selecting all rows where it is "Apple". But maybe you are thinking that the code was just getting that row but keeping the other rows ~somewhere else~, but that's not the case ^_^

Answer (score 4):

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(name = replace(name, which(name == 'Apple'),
                        list(c('Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Dragonfruit')))) %>% 
  unnest_longer(name)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   name         val1  val2
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Kiwi            1     1
#> 2 Orange          9     1
#> 3 Apple          10     1
#> 4 Strawberry     10     1
#> 5 Dragonfruit    10     1
```

or

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(name = if_else(name != 'Apple', name,
                        paste(name, 'Strawberry', 'Dragonfruit'))) %>% 
  separate_rows(name, sep = ' ')
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   name         val1  val2
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Kiwi            1     1
#> 2 Orange          9     1
#> 3 Apple          10     1
#> 4 Strawberry     10     1
#> 5 Dragonfruit    10     1
```

or

```r
df %>% 
  filter(name == 'Apple') %>% 
  reframe(name = c('Strawberry', 'Dragonfruit'), across(-name)) %>% 
  bind_rows(df, .)
#>          name val1 val2
#> 1        Kiwi    1    1
#> 2      Orange    9    1
#> 3       Apple   10    1
#> 4  Strawberry   10    1
#> 5 Dragonfruit   10    1
```

or

```r
df %>% 
  filter(name == 'Apple') %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  expand_grid(name = c('Strawberry', 'Dragonfruit')) %>% 
  bind_rows(df, .)
#>          name val1 val2
#> 1        Kiwi    1    1
#> 2      Orange    9    1
#> 3       Apple   10    1
#> 4  Strawberry   10    1
#> 5 Dragonfruit   10    1
```

or

```r
df %>% 
  uncount(if_else(name == 'Apple', 3, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(name = replace(name, which(name == 'Apple')[-1],
                        c('Strawberry', 'Dragonfruit')))
#>          name val1 val2
#> 1        Kiwi    1    1
#> 2      Orange    9    1
#> 3       Apple   10    1
#> 4  Strawberry   10    1
#> 5 Dragonfruit   10    1
```

Comment: thank you for this! I was trying to think of other approaches to "get" a row and apply transformations rather than filtering df for the row I want and rbinding it back in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  add_row(name = "Strawberry") |>
  add_row(name = "Dragonfruit") |>
  fill(val1:val2)
#          name val1 val2
# 1        Kiwi    1    1
# 2      Orange    9    1
# 3       Apple   10    1
# 4  Strawberry   10    1
# 5 Dragonfruit   10    1
```

Alternatively, you could define a small function to create a tibble that you can then append (by default `add_row` will append, but you can specify where to insert the new row using the `.before` or `.after` arguments -- see below):

```r
new_row <- function(new, old = "Apple") {
  df |>
    filter(name == old) |>
    mutate(name = new)
}

df |>
  add_row(new_row("Strawberry")) |>
  add_row(new_row("Dragonfruit")) |>
  add_row(new_row("Banana", "Kiwi"), .after = 1)
#          name val1 val2
# 1        Kiwi    1    1
# 2      Banana    1    1
# 3      Orange    9    1
# 4       Apple   10    1
# 5  Strawberry   10    1
# 6 Dragonfruit   10    1
```

Comment: I gather this would be dependent on `name == 'Apple'` always being the last row?

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, by default that is the assumption of the first solution I posted.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, though I was looking for a solution wherein I don't need to know the position in the dataframe of the record I'm looking to duplicate.

Comment: @BrendaThompson you do not need to know the position of the second solution.

Comment: gotchya, thank you! I appreciate that you wrote a function as one of your approaches. helps me understand/visualize in a broader sense all the options available to accomplish the same task.